# Get id on form submit and enter into phpmailer email

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email, phpmailer

I created a ticket system that does the following: (FYI st_id is the id in my table)

- User fills out form and hits submit
- After submit it takes the info from the form and emails to me via phpmailer
- During the email process it also enters all info into a support ticket table

The problem I'm having is I use the support_ticket tables st_id as the ticket number.

When a user fills out the form, the entry is emailing all the form data first and not acquiring the st_id number.

I need the st_id number to show in the email.

**So I'm looking for help on how to get the st_id / ticket number to email with the other data.**

Here is what my database looks like.

[image]

And here is what the email that gets delivered to me looks like:

[image]

**In the action script I have the following.**

```
// form data

$ticket_type    = $_POST['ticket_type'];
$subject        = $_POST['subject'];
$content        = $_POST['content'];
$user_id        = $_POST['user_id'];
$unit           = $_POST['unit'];
$first_name     = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name      = $_POST['last_name'];
$email          = $_POST['email'];
$phone          = $_POST['phone'];
$st_id          = $_POST['st_id'];

// query



$addticket = DB::getInstance()->insert('support_ticket', array(

    //'st_id'           => $st_id,
    'ticket_type'   => $ticket_type,
    'subject'       => $subject,
    'content'       => $content,
    'user_id'       => $user_id,
    'unit'          => $unit,
    'first_name'    => $first_name,
    'last_name'     => $last_name,
    'email'         => $email,
    'phone'         => $phone

));
```

**Then the email section:**

```
User::sendNewticket('myemail@fake.com', 'Subject of email', '<strong>'.Input::get('first_name') .' '.Input::get('last_name').'</strong>, from unit <strong>'.Input::get('unit').',</strong> ' . 'has called in a maintenance ticket for the following:<br><br>

<strong>Ticket Number:</strong> '.Input::get('st_id') .'<br><br>
<strong>Ticket Type:</strong> '.Input::get('ticket_type') .'<br><br>
<strong>Subject:</strong> '.Input::get('subject') .'<br><br>
<strong>Message:</strong> '.Input::get('content') .'<br><br>
....etc
```

I need to find a way to get `<strong>Ticket Number:</strong> '.Input::get('st_id') .'` this to work.

I think I need to write a query that grabs the st_id from the table and Posts it to the email script before the email is sent, but again not sure how to get that to work.

Any ideas or solutions would be much appreciated. If you need me to post more code let me know. I tried to keep it to a minimum of what was relevant.

Comment: pls don't post double-spaced code.

Comment: I don't see the code that actually does the work. The logic should be: 1. Do the insert, 2. Get [LAST_INSERT_ID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) (missing) 3. Send the mail.

Comment: The query doesn't look right. You have `WHERE st_id = ?`, but there's no parameter to fill in the `?` placeholder. It also makes no sense to do that query -- `SELECT st_id FROM table where st_id = ?` just returns the same ID that you input to the query.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I wasn't sure what to do there. thinking about it I dont think I need that hidden field anyways, what do you think?

Comment: Also, if you pput a placeholder inside quotes, it's not a placeholder any more. You're looking for tickets whose ID matches the string `?`, and none of them will (if it's a numeric field, `?` will be converted to the number `0`).

Comment: If the user is creating a new ticket, then there isn't an ID before they fill it out, so there's nothing to put in the hidden field. The ID is assigned when you create the ticket in the DB. As @VMai said, you add the ticket to the DB, get the ID that was assigned, and put that in the mail.

Comment: @Barmar yes that's exactly what I need, but never used the LAST_INSERT_ID in a query. I'll try and figure out how to write that query.

Comment: Most database APIs also provide a way to get it. See [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) and [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

Comment: @VMai could you help me out with the `LAST_INSERT_ID` ? In my situation I'm a little confused on how to use it to get the st_id into my email. I tried something like this:`$st_id = $addticket->lastInsertId();` Then did `Ticket Number: '.$st_id.'` in my email section, but I must be way off here.

Comment: I don't know what DB class you're using. There should be - as @Barmar mentioned - a way to get id via the class directly. Otherwise use something like a raw query in the form of `DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');` or so. It depends of how your (for us unknown) DB class is working.

Comment: @VMai here is my DB class http://pastebin.com/JYp2w9HP . Been trying to use a raw query, just not getting it. I apologize for my lack of knowledge here. Just really want to get this working.

Comment: @echo, you're nearly there - `$addticket` isn't a PDO instance so that won't work, try `$st_id = DB::getInstance()->lastInsertId();` just after your insert and it will return the ID of the newly inserted record, no need to do another query for it.

Comment: @Synchro thanks for the tip , but I keep getting `Call to undefined method DB::lastInsertId()` . 

In my DB.php class I added `public function lastInsertedId() { return $this->_pdo->lastInsertId(); }` You can see my DB class here. http://pastebin.com/JYp2w9HP This is prior to adding the new lastInsert function.

Comment: Never mind I had `lastInsertedId()` instead or `lastInsertId()` in my DB.php class. Problem solved and working. Thanks guys.

Comment: Ah, ok, I had assumed that `getInstance()` returned the PDO instance directly, not your wrapper for it. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under this Insert query I added:

```
$addticket = DB::getInstance()->insert('support_ticket', array(

    //'st_id'           => $st_id,
    'ticket_type'   => $ticket_type,
    'subject'       => $subject,
    'content'       => $content,
    'user_id'       => $user_id,
    'unit'          => $unit,
    'first_name'    => $first_name,
    'last_name'     => $last_name,
    'email'         => $email,
    'phone'         => $phone

));

$st_id = DB::getInstance()->lastInsertId();
```

In my DB.php class file I had to add this:

```
public function lastInsertId() {
return $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
}
```

Then finally in my email section I simply added this to retrieve the Ticket number.

```
Ticket Number: '.$st_id.'
```